# std::map::operator[] is more efficient than std::map::insert?

Tags: c++, stl

I've learnt that **operator[]** is equivalent to

```
(*((this->insert(make_pair(k,mapped_type()))).first)).second
```

So if a key doesn't exist in the map, using **operator[]** is less efficient than using **insert**, right? Because there's one more step, default construct.

So I wrote a demo to test, like this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

static int id = 0;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
        : _val(0)
    {
        _id = ++id;
        cout << _id << " construct_no_param:" << _val << endl;
    }
    Foo(int val)
        : _val(val)
    {
        _id = ++id;
        cout << _id << " construct_has_param:" << _val << endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo &rhs)
        : _val(rhs._val)
    {
        _id = ++id;
        cout << _id << " construct_copy:" << _val << endl;
    }
    Foo(const Foo &rhs)
        : _val(rhs._val)
    {
        _id = ++id;
        cout << _id << " construct_const_copy:" << _val << endl;
    }
    Foo &operator=(Foo &rhs)
    {
        _val = rhs._val;
        cout << _id << " assign:" << _val << endl;
    }
    Foo &operator=(const Foo &rhs)
    {
        _val = rhs._val;
        cout << _id << " const_assign:" << _val << endl;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        cout << _id << " destruct:" << _val << endl;
    }

    int _val;
    int _id;
};

int main() {
    map<int, Foo> m;
    const Foo f(2);
    cout << "-----" << endl;
    // m[1] = f;
    // m.insert(make_pair(1, f));
    cout << "-----" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

First, I used **operator[]**

```
    m[1] = f;
```

And I got this:

```
1 construct_has_param:2
-----
2 construct_no_param:0
3 construct_const_copy:0
4 construct_const_copy:0
3 destruct:0
2 destruct:0
4 assign:2
-----
1 destruct:2
4 destruct:2
```

Then, I used **insert**

```
    m.insert(make_pair(1, f));
```

And I got this:

```
1 construct_has_param:2
-----
2 construct_const_copy:2
3 construct_const_copy:2
4 construct_const_copy:2
5 construct_const_copy:2
4 destruct:2
3 destruct:2
2 destruct:2
-----
1 destruct:2
5 destruct:2
```

The results are not correspond to what I'm expected. Why `insert` has more constructions? What's going on here?

BTW, I use -O0 option to disable optimization, but I'm not sure if it works.

gcc version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-8) (GCC)

Comment: A 2013 compiler is pretty old. GCC is currently in version 10.2. I don't know if GCC 4.8.2 optimizes copy constructors, either at -O0 or at -O2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `make_pair(1, f)` has type `std::pair<int, Foo>`, which isn't your maps `value_type`, which is `std::pair<const int, Foo>`, so there is a copy in the arguments of `insert`. There then are 2 copies within `map`, that would be moves if all your special members didn't suppress the generation of move construction.

If you want to avoid as much copying as you can, use [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)

```
m.emplace(1, f);
```

and define `Foo`'s move constructor and assignment

```
Foo(Foo &&rhs)
    : _val(std::exchange(rhs.val, 0))
{
    _id = ++id;
    cout << _id << " move:" << _val << endl;
}

Foo& opeator=(Foo &&rhs)
{
    std::swap(_val, rhs._val);
    cout << _id << " move assign:" << _val << endl;
}
```

I would also recommend dropping the non-const copy operations.

Comment: I use --std=c++11 to recompile, and like you said, the last two copies within `map` are turned into moves. But for the first two copies in `insert`, I still have questions. For the first copy, like you said, is constructing a special struct, but why `operator[]` doesn't have this step? For the second copy, can you explain more? I still don't get why it has to copy initialise a `std::pair<const int, Foo>`.

Comment: The expression `make_pair(1, f)` has type `std::pair<int, Foo>`. map's value type is `std::pair<const int, Foo>`. At no point is `[]` copying pairs. You copy assign the `Foo` onto the `Foo &` reference.